# First order axioms for sequence theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms, multisets

In a set the repetition and order of the elements does not matter.

In a multiset the order fo the elements does not matter, but the repetitions do.

In a sequence both the order and the repetition matter.

Is there any first order logic and axiomatic formulation of sequences, more or less comparable to the ZFC axioms of set theory?

Comment: DEISER, OLIVER's AN AXIOMATIC THEORY OF WELL-ORDERINGS. The Review of Symbolic Logic, 4(2), 186–204. 
presented a axiomatic theory of lists, which is equiconsistent with zfc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that I correctly identified the point of your question. So please let me know whether the following answer is what you are looking for:

Within any reasonably rich set theory we can formalize the notion of multisets and sequences. $\operatorname{ZFC}$ is, obviously, an overkill to do so. But it's the theory most mathematicians (even if they don't know it explicitly) are familiar with. So, for the sake of this answer, let's work within $\operatorname{ZFC}$.

The "standard" approach to multisets and sequences, within $\operatorname{ZFC}$ is as follows:

*Step 1.* Unordered pairs.

Let $V$ be our set theoretic universe. We want to find a (definable class function)
$$
\langle, \rangle \colon V \times V \to V, \ (x,y) \mapsto \langle x, y \rangle
$$
that satisfies the fundamental property of a pairing function. Namely, for all $a,b,c,d \in V$,

$$\langle a,b \rangle = \langle c, d \rangle \iff a = c \wedge b = d$$

The *Kuratowski* pairing function
$$
\langle a, b \rangle := \{ \{a\}, \{a,b\} \}
$$
does provably satisfy this condition (in $\operatorname{ZFC}$).

*Step 2.* Cartesian products.

Once we have a pairing function, we can define the *Cartesian product* of two sets $X,Y$ as
$$
X \times Y := \{ \langle x,y \rangle \mid x \in X \wedge y \in Y \}.
$$

(This apparently circular use of Cartesian products can be avoided by a taking a little more care and talking about the actual formula defining the pairing function above.)

*Step 3.* Functions.

Once we have Cartesian products, we can define functions. A function $f$ with domain $X$ and range $Y$ is a subset
$$
f \subseteq X \times Y
$$
such that for all $x \in X$ there is a unique $y \in Y$ such that $\langle x, y \rangle \in f$.

*Step 4.* Multisets.

By the axiom of infinity, the set of natural numbers (including $0$!) $\mathbb N$ exists. A *multiset* $M$ with domain $X$ is a function
$$
M \colon X \to \mathbb N
$$
$x \in X$ is a member of $M$ iff $M(x) > 0$ and $M(x)$ is the multiplicity of $x$ in $M$.

It's easy to define the usual operations on multisets. For example, if $M, N$ are multisets with domain $X$ and $Y$ respectively, we can define the union multiset $M \sqcup N$ with domain $X \cup Y$ as follows:

$$
M \sqcup N \colon X \cup Y \to \mathbb N, \ z \mapsto M(z) + N(z).
$$

*Step 5.* Sequences.

A (countable) sequence $S$ with domain $X$ is a function
$$
S \colon \mathbb N \to X
$$
where $S(n)$ is the $n$-th element of the sequence $S$.

Viewed this way multisets and sequences are sort of dual notions and - modulo the intended interpretation - actually are the same objects when there domain happens to be $\mathbb N$.